# How do I download whole folder from OneDrive onto my SD card?

Tags: onedrive

How do I download whole folder from OneDrive onto my SD card?
Exactly what an app called Folder Downloader (that works only for Dropbox) does for Dropbox - but getting a folder from OneDrive.

reliability is important. Also if 7 files out of 40 fail - the app should offer re-try of just those files.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to sync / download entire content of your OneDrive to your SD Card _using your desktop computer_ and then only setup OneDrive to work on that folder / root folder on your SD Card? It should do some indexing / cleanup work and you should be done. At least this is how I'm doing this with each fresh installation on OneDrive on my PCs. Instead of wasting hours to download a few GBs of data over Internet I simply copy entire content of OneDrive folder from old computer to new one and then indexing takes few minutes at most.

Comment: no because my onderive is 100GB and it would be too much to sync.